# separating file contents located between two characters into separate files

Tags: linux, unix

I have a file.txt with various numbers separated by brackets:

```
[133,406,789] [126,234,645]
```

I'd like to parse all numbers within brackets to a separate files:

```
file1.txt:
    [133,406,789]
file2.txt:
    [126,234,645]
...
...
file50.txt: [174,874,99,21,34]
```

I have tried to use this command:

```
cat file.txt | sed s/[/\\n/g
```

This is what I get:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that there are spaces between the square brackets and nowhere else then

```
awk '{n=split($0, tmp, /[[:space:]]+/); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print tmp[i] > "file_" fno++;}'
```

will do it. Otherwise, you need to make your regex a little more clever. Alternatively you can look at the 'csplit' shell command.

Comment: I will have a look at csplit. Every begining ' [ ' starts on a fresh line. So, there would be space between the ' ] ' on the preceding line and the new ' [ ' on the subsequent line.

Comment: That would never be a problem because 'awk' processes your file line by line. I meant spaces between ][ on the same line (of course you are free to enforce that by a well place 'sed' command).

Comment: Here is what I tried with csplit:
csplit -s -f parse file.txt  '/^[/' {*}
and this is what I get: csplit: /^[/: invalid regular expression: Invalid regular expression

Comment: '[' is the beginning of a character class so you need to escape it '\['. The 'awk' script works perfectly, why worry about 'csplit'?

Comment: The command almost worked. It split all numbers into one file each (number + comma or bracket). For example: file1- [133, file2- 406,.... file400- 34]

Comment: I should clarify the contents of one bracket sometimes traverses several lines.

Comment: fmt -w 100000 yourfile will reformat your input file on one line, so all opening and closing brackets will be on one line.

Comment: Tried to place everything on one file line with the above fmt command and this is what if get: fmt: invalid width: `100000'.

Comment: The issue was finally resolved by removing all white space in the file via sed: # sed 's/\s//g' file.txt | tr -d '\n' 
I then used gedit to replace all end brackets ']' with the new line character ']\n'

Comment: Finally, I used this awk command: 
awk '{n=split($0, tmp, /[[:space:]]+/); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print tmp[i] > "file_" fno++;}' file.txt

Comment: If you replaced all '] ' with ']\n' you no longer need the for loop in the awk command. That was iterating over bracketed numbers on a single line. And you could have used sed -E s/\]/\]\n/ instead of gedit. Oh well.